# kRNCryptorAES256Settings referenced error

Tags: ios, swift, rncryptor

I am trying to use RNCryptor in my app to do some data encryption.

Look at the code below:

```
 var encryptedData: NSData = RNEncryptor.encryptData(data, withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings, password: aPassword, error: nil)
```

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_kRNCryptorAES256Settings", referenced from:
>         __TFC8UtraceUI24ChatBubbleViewController21textFieldShouldReturnfS0_FCSo11UITextFieldSb
>   in ChatBubbleViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture
>   i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

I am not sure why does it try to look for the constant name with an underscore; ideally it should have tried to look for kRNCryptorAES256Settings which is their in the bridgesupport and other header files.

Any clue what might be going wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? If Swift 2 please update the tag.

Comment: No I am not using swift 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift cannot deal with C Structs, which is what kRNCryptorAES256Settings is. This issue has nothing to do with the architecture of the devices.

So to go around that, I created my own method in RNEcryptor with the sole reason to abstract the need of the C struct.

```
+ (NSData *)EncryptDataForSwift:(NSData *)data password:(NSString *)password error:(NSError **)error
{
    return [RNEncryptor encryptData:data withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:password error:error];
}
```

I am not sure whether it good idea or not, but this makes my project compilable, as I can call my method via Swift without needing to reference any C-only code:

```
var encryptedData:NSData = RNEncryptor.EncryptDataForSwift(data, password: Password, error: nil)
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Is this the latest ObjC release (3.0.1). I thought I'd fixed that already. Is this an old version of Xcode perhaps?

Comment: For Swift, that's very out of date. It's not surprising you're having trouble. Current versions of Swift can certainly deal with C structs (even in Swift 1.2).

Comment: Ok. Good to know that. Thanks for the info and your time as well.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to include the `.m` files as part of your build. Check the "Build Sources" step in your Build Phases.

If you're working in Swift, you may want to look at the [new Swift version](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/tree/RNCryptor-4.0.0-beta.1). That'll merge to master next week.

Comment: The file is there in Build Sources.